Async gather calls for dynamic number of API calls
I have a unique situation. I am creating a common code utility where I am tasked to improve performance by making an API calls asynchronous. Most programs are having 6 to 10 same API calls to read different values. Idea is to make those API calls at start in asynchronous way. For example write a method which will take an array of string (Keys) and trigger async calls like below for each key.
results = await asyncio.gather( 
call_api(key1), 
call_api(key2),
call_api(key3)
)

number of keys are dynamic. What is the best way to write this code to make dynamic number of call_api/API calls in python?

I think you're looking for unpack operator (*):
# ...

keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]  # <-- dynamic list of all keys

api_calls_tasks = [asyncio.create_task(call_api(k)) for k in keys]

results = await asyncio.gather(*api_calls_tasks)

